# The loop doesn't stopped even when I used the same way to write it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop, python-requests

## Not working

```
def player_input():
marker = ''
while 'X' or 'O' not in marker:
      marker = input("Choose between 'X' or 'O': ")
      print ("Please choose between 'X' or 'O'")
     
if marker == 'X':
    return ('X', 'O')
else:
    return ('O', 'X')
```

## Working code

```
def player_input():
marker = ''
while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
    marker = input("Choose between 'X' or 'O': ")
    print ("Please choose between 'X' or 'O'")
     
if marker == 'X':
    return ('X', 'O')
else:
    return ('O', 'X')
```

*I ran both but the loop doesn't stops in first. What is the difference between two?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: You're first `while` loop is seen as `while ('X') or ('O' not in number):`. Since `'X'` evaluates to True the loop will run forever.

Comment: In "while 'X' or ..." the 'X' is already interpreted as true so the whole condition is true regardless of the things following after "or".

Comment: no @jasonharper

Comment: thanks @Matthias I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

you have indentation error. the if statement is not in the loop. try this code. while loop only run once, because you used else in if statement

```
def player_input():
    marker = ''
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = input("Please choose between 'X' or 'O' >")
        if marker == 'X':
            return ('X', 'O')
        else:
            return ('O', 'X')
print( player_input() )
```